# Getting the vendor of the used JRE since Java 9

Tags: java, java-9, java-platform-module-system

Until 8, it was possible to get some information on the vendor of the used JRE as follows:

```java
String vendor = Runtime.class.getPackage().getImplementationVendor().
```

Since Java 9 and the introduction of the Java Module System, the method call above returns always `null`.

How can I get the same information with current Java plattforms?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Get the value from the system properties:

```java
String vendor = System.getProperty("java.vm.vendor");
```

That is a [documented](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#getProperties()) property, so should always be there.